# creating an sshd server using apache libraries requires me to alter the commands server side but it works if i connect to another ssh server

Tags: java, git, ssh, sshd, copssh

Requirements:
Write my own ssh server that allows `msysgit` to communicate with a repo (`pull`, `push`, etc) using the ssh protocol and going though my ssh server.  I'm running on Windows 7.

using `git remote` definition of:

```
git remote set-url origin "ssh://test@localhost:22/C/gittestserver"
```

does not work through my ssh server, but does work if I go through another ssh server such as `copssh`.

Using a remote of the following and also doing manual manipulation of the command on my ssh server works:

```
git remote set-url origin "ssh://test@localhost:22/C:\gittestserver"
```

I get the following command in my ssh server using the original remote url `git-receive-pack '/C/gittestserver'` which does not work.
To get the above to work, i have to manually remove the single quote from the beginning and end of the second parameter, and I also have to remove the `/` from the beginning of the second parameter.  After doing this manual command manipulation I can get git to work successfully.

Is there a way to avoid doing this manual manipulation or do it the proper way so that I don't break potential future use cases?  Somehow other ssh servers on windows don't have this problem (`copssh`).

please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904887/using-git-with-apache-sshd) ("Using Git with Apache sshd") for more information.

Comment: [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) supports SSH access out of the box as long as your JDK does. Perhaps try that?

Comment: Thanks, but i'm writing the server side.  I want to use existing software to go across my server.  I figure this should have something to do with the shell i configure for the server, but changing it seems to have no affect on the parsing.